# Why? My website is not showing "cache option" in search result

Tags: google-search-console, 404, cache

Plz guide me. Why? my website is not showing "cache option" in search result.  when I check Ex- (Cache: http://example.com ) then it shows - 
"404. That’s an error."  URLs are indexed & no any issues in search console.   We dropped my ranking due to it. so plz

Comment: We've been getting several questions about this lately, so it seems you're not the only one. Please see the linked questions and answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not have a cached copy of the url (not website).

Google takes a snapshot of the url as of when *Google* last crawled it ([source](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1687222?hl=en)).

Not having one means either:

1. there is no cached version of the url; or
2. there is only one cached version (the current one) so a drop down is redundant.

Keep in mind that while you may have made various changes to the url, that does not mean that Google has cached all the changes - typical with 'younger' sites.

Hope that helps.